# What are downsides of stop doing physical activities?

Tags: exercise, sports, exercise-frequency, sports-psychology

What if you completely stop doing sports? Including walks or any other physical activity besides necessary as going to work/store/etc. Is there any medical researches on how it will affect your health, quality of life or life expectancy?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well documented that a sedentary lifestyle is bad in many ways, including overall health, which impacts your QoL, and life expectancy.

From WHO https://www.who.int/news/item/04-04-2002-physical-inactivity-a-leading-cause-of-disease-and-disability-warns-who:

> Physical inactivity can have serious implications for people’s health, said the World Health Organization today on the occasion of World Health Day. Approximately 2 million deaths per year are attributed to physical inactivity, prompting WHO to issue a warning that a sedentary lifestyle could very well be among the 10 leading causes of death and disability in the world.

Comment: I'm just thinking if time saved on avoiding activities will be greater or less than decrease of your life time and how much activities must do someone who really not into it.

Comment: That’s why I mentioned quality of life as well: living the same amount but with a worse quality of life (mental and physical) is not a gain.